# Is the inverse of a smooth bi-Lipschitz map continuously differentiable?

Tags: derivatives, continuity, inverse-function, lipschitz-functions, inverse-function-theorem

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ be smooth (i.e. $C^\infty$) and bi-Lipschitz. Is the inverse $f^{-1}$ in $C^1$?
If we knew that $\nabla f$ was invertible, this would follow immediately from the inverse function theorem. However, in this setting I am not sure if the statement is true and have not been able to prove it. Also, by Rademacher's theorem we get that the inverse is differentiable a.e., but not *continuous* differentiability (continuous differentiability a.e. would suffice, however).

Comment: The invertibility of $df(x)$ at every $x$ follows from the assumption bi-Lipschitz. If $df(x)$ was not invertible, taking a non null vector in the kernel of $df(x)$, you would have $t^{-1}[f(x+h)-f(x)] \to 0$, which would contradict that $f^{-1}$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: True, that makes sense, thank you!